# Как подключиться к очереди брокера сообщений?

Tags: python, rabbitmq

долго ломаю голову, прошу помогите.

У меня есть адрес, логин(guest), пароль(guest) и название очереди, к которой мне нужно подключиться удаленно (мне прислали и нужно подключиться). Язык разработки - Python.

Очень прошу помочь!

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: ну а брокер какой? redis, например, или rabbitmq? по названию брокера ищите python+брокер - 100% найдете простые примеры.

Comment: RabbitrMQ. Я искал, но везде почему то приводят в пример подключению к очереди localhost, а мне нужно подключиться к определенному адресу.